# is this MySql assertion correct?

Tags: mysql

is the following MySql assertion syntactically correct?
create assertion RD1_assert
check  User.num_video   =  select count(*)
                                                   from Video
                                                   where Video.user= User.Nick

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check empty set in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913327/how-to-check-empty-set-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

No, because MySQL does not support assertions!

Answer (score 0):

Mysql does not support assertion so you could use trigger and store procedure instead of assertion.