# Constrain table entries on sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design, constraints

I have 3 related tables as shown in the image below.

[image: Db Diagram]

Everyone has an entry in the User table and a UserRole.
Some Users are Subscribers.

I want to constrain the Subscribers table so that it can only contain users whose role IsSusbcriber but retain the UserRole at User level. Is it possible?

Excuse the current relationships between the table, they represent whats there at the moment rather whats necessarily needed.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? DB2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could drop the `IsSubscriber` columns and add a `UserSubscriberRoles` table that will contain exactly those roles that had previously set the `IsSubscriber` column.

```
CREATE UserSubscriberRoles
  ( UserRoleId PRIMARY KEY
  , FOREIGN KEY (UserRoleId)
      REFERENCES UserRoles (UserRoleId) 
  ) ;
```

Then change the FKs in `Subscribers` table to:

```
   FOREIGN KEY (UserId, UserRoleId)
     REFERENCES User (UserId, UserRoleId) 
   FOREIGN KEY (UserRoleId)
     REFERENCES UserSubscriberRoles (UserRoleId)
```

Comment: Precisely what I was thinking. :)

Comment: Thanks ypercube, this is what I'll go with

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible?

In theory, yes; you can use a SQL assertion. See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4920994/978917) for an example.

In practice, however, no major DBMS supports SQL assertions, and what you describe cannot be implemented as a foreign-key constraint, so I think your only option is to write a [trigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) that evaluates this constraint, and raises an exception if it's not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to contrain this without RoleId in the table is via either a trigger (and triggers are usually a bad design choice), or a SQL Agent job that periodically removes people from Subscribers that don't fit the criteria.

With RoleID in Subscribers, you can add a check constraint that limits it to a specific value.

This would really be better enforced with a different design and/or in the application code.